# Sitecore DMS custom visitor classification

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I am trying to implement custom visitor classification.
I defined my custom types in master database under and published them
/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Visitor Identifications

And I set the visitor classification upon login using api call
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor.SetVisitorClassification(member.MemberType, member.MemberType, false);

But I was still getting my visits in visit detail report as Anonymous, upon digging I found that [VisitorClassifications] table in analytics database still doesn't have my custom Visitor Identifications.

Is there something I need to do get the custom "Visitor Identifications" I already defined in sitecore in to analytics database ? I wonder if making manual entry in to that database is the right way ? Would I break something ?

Answer (score 0):

Open **Control Panel** and click on '**Analytics**' Link.

Then you can find a link called '**Update Visitor Classification**'

This will launch a wizard. It says, '**This wizard will help you : Update visitor classifications in the Analytics database.**'

Try this. I think this should help you.